# How to show length menu of DataTable JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How to show length menu of a JQuery DataTable? It disappear upon activating exportation **(COPY, EXCEL, PDF)**. I already added the `lengthMenu` but it is not showing the drop down. This is what i did:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        lengthChange: false,
        buttons: [ 'copy', 'excel', 'pdf' ],
        responsive: true,
        'columnDefs': [ {
                'targets': [6], /* column index */
                'orderable': false, /* true or false */
                'lengthMenu': [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
        }]
    } );
    table.buttons().container().appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)' );
} );
```

I am using the jquery 3.3.1 and datatables 1.10.19 via cdn.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the `dom` param like `dom: 'Blfrtip'`.
See also the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        lengthChange: true,
        buttons: [ 'copy', 'excel', 'pdf' ],
        responsive: true,
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        columnDefs: [ {
                targets: [6], /* column index */
                orderable: false, /* true or false */
                lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
        }]
    } );
    table.buttons.container.appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)' );
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Example</th>
      <th>Example</th>
      <th>Example</th>
      <th>Example</th>
      <th>Example</th>
      <th>Example</th>
      <th>Example</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add `dom`:

> dom: 'Bflrtip'

[read more about datatables dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)

and ***lengthMenu*** position should be fixed

and ***lengthChange*** should be `true`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        lengthChange: true,
        dom: 'Bflrtip', 
        buttons: [ 'copy', 'excel', 'pdf' ],
        responsive: true,
        'columnDefs': [ {
                'targets': [6], /* column index */
                'orderable': false, /* true or false */
        }],
        'lengthMenu': [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
    } );
    table.buttons().container().appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)' );
} );
```

Comment: Is is possible to vertically align length menu and the search bar? If so how?

Comment: @AnirudhLou This question is not about your problem, please edit your question or ask new question.

Comment: adding `dom: "Bflrtip"` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the dom settings like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        lengthChange: false,
        buttons: [ 'copy', 'excel', 'pdf' ],
        responsive: true,
        dom: 'lfrtip',
        'columnDefs': [ {
                'targets': [6], /* column index */
                'orderable': false, /* true or false */
                'lengthMenu': [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
        }]
    } );
    table.buttons().container().appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)' );
} );
```

For more information see answers on this [forum discussion](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40387)